# Anyone successfully installed RIDE on MAC?

Tags: macos, wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I tried installing RIDE on MAC, but repeatedly failing to do so.
If anyone did it, please share the worked steps.

I could get following error:

```
Wrong wxPython version.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

Downloaded wxpython 2.8.12.1 from the above link, but couldn't install. Could someone help me here. It'll be of great help.

Comment: What does "couldn't install" mean? Why couldn't you install wxpython?

Comment: from brew installation, it installs latest version (3.0.2) by default. Can't degrade it. I need to install 2.8.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome problems when installing wxPython 2.8.12.1, you should:

1. Download the .dmg package (must be the unicode one)
2. Mount the disk
3. Open the disk and copy the zipped .pkg to your hard disk
4. Install (acknowledge any security warnings)

Maybe you need to temporarily allow to install uncertified packages.

Comment: I copied *.pkg to mounted disk and then double clicked on it. I could see this popup "wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-flat-package-py2.7.pkg” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer".

Comment: So, you need to see how to change Mac OS X security settings to allow installation from unidentified developer.